# Semi-rigid dryer duct in contact with PVC drain pipe

Tags: dryer, vent

I just installed a dryer vent using semi-rigid aluminum duct.  Approximately 7' from where the semi-rigid duct attaches to the dryer at floor level, the duct touches a black PVC drain at ceiling level. The surface to surface contact is probably less than 2 inches.  Can the heat from the semi-rigid duct damage or even melt the PVC drain pipe?  I suspect the heat from the dryer has dissipated sufficiently at 7' but I have no experience doing this type of work. Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: FYI black plastic plumbing is ABS not PVC. It shouldn't make any material difference to your question, but they have slightly different properties.

Comment: Thank you Matthew.  I've learned a lot in the last 2 days and you have been part of that process.  It seems that ABS is actually somewhat more heat resistant than PVC.

Answer (score 2):

The floor level vent being the damp air exhaust it will not get hot enough to melt the PVC or do any other damage unless there is a lint fire in the pipe. Cleaning the pipe once a year will keep a fire from having fuel to burn.